# Same number of poles an ceros of rational complex map

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $R(z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ with $P,Q$ polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[z]$, such that $P^{-1}(0) \cap Q^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$, then $R: \overline{\mathbb{C}}\to \overline{\mathbb{C}}$

defining $R(z) = \infty$ if $z \in Q^{-1}(0)$

There is a claim that taking with multiplicity ceros and poles of $R$ we have:

$$\# \text{Zeros of }R = \# \text{Poles of }R = max\{deg(P),deg(Q)\}$$

and i have trouble with the case $deg(P)>deg(Q)$ as $R(\infty) \neq 0$ then $R(z) = 0 \iff P(z) = 0$ and the amount of zeros is $deg(P)$ but the amount of poles is $deg(Q) \neq deg(P) $

---

The case $deg(P)<deg(Q)$ is okay because $\infty$ will be a zero of multiplicity $deg(Q)-deg(P)$ plus de zeros os $P$ wich are deg(P) we get $deg(Q)$ zeros.

I think the problem may be in the definition of poles od a rational funtion, that i think is the amount of zeros of the denominator.

Comment: I don't think what you wrote is true. If $P(z)$ is a nonzero constant and $Q(z)=z-1$. Then $R$ has no zeros and one pole. Maybe you need to to check your claim.

Comment: infinity is a pole for $P/Q$ of order degree $P-$ degree $Q$ when $deg(P)>deg(Q)$ @Tri in your example $R(\infty)=0$

Comment: i belive by taking the definition of z is pole of $R$ if it is a zero of $1/R$ or $R$ would be okay as i didn't knew what the degre of $R(\infty)$ be in the problem case

Comment: @FranAguayo I think it may help considering $R(1/z)$. Then the degree of $\infty$ is just the order of $z=0$ of $R(1/z)$, which is $\deg P - \deg Q$. Sorry for the confusing comment above, as Conrad pointed out, I didn't count $\infty$ as a pole.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help in the coments, the problem was that in the case of $deg(P)>deg(Q)$, $\infty$ is not a cero but it is a pole since $R(\infty) = \infty$, with multiplicity the degre of cero in $R(1/z)$ and in that case multiplying by $\frac{z^{deg(P)}}{z^{deg(P)}}$ we end up in the case that did work.